# Using qwt with qt_ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a qt_ros package which uses a custom .ui file with a couple of qwt widgets. The standard qt_ros package builds and displays the original main window gui. When I replace the old .ui file with the one I want to use, I get the message `qwt_dial.h: No such file or directory`. I have confirmed that the files exist in `usr/include/qwt-qt4`. The only thing I can think of is maybe there should be lines including qwt in package.xml and/or CMakeLists.txt, or qwt should be installed elsewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

edit: Earlier I added the path to the widget library to ui_main_window.h which is generated with catkin_make. This allowed the file to be found. It was then giving me an error with slot and signal; those had to be changed to Q_SLOT and Q_SIGNAL. Currently I am getting a few undefined reference errors involving QwtCompass and QwtDial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211846/using-qwt-with-qt_ros/) by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, It started to work magically. Here is what I did: In ui_main_window.h change "#include qwtcompass.h" to "#include qwt-qt4/qwt_compass.h". This change has to be repeated every time the .ui file is altered, for now. In qwt_abstract_scale_draw.h the lines "slots" and "signals" must be changed to "Q_SLOTS" and "Q_SIGNALS" respectively. In CMakeLists.txt, "${Qwt_LIBRARIES}" must be added to the list of "target_link_libraries()".

---

Originally posted by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) with karma: 107 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
file(GLOB QWT_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include/qwt")
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QWT_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

and

```
file(GLOB QWT_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/libqwt*")
target_link_libraries(<your_program> ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${QWT_LIBRARIES})
```

worked for me.

My qwt stuff were in /usr/include/qwt folder; not in /usr/include/qwt-qt4

cheers!

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karem](https://answers.ros.org/users/70373/karem/) on 2021-07-01**:
This solution worked for me!!
thanks